# Android XML Weird insertion

Tags: android, xml

When I first examine my program's (C#, Xamarin, Android) XML files in one file activity_main.xml, some process inserts these:

```
            <TextView
                android:minWidth="30px"
                android:minHeight="30px"
                xmlns="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                android:id="@+id/textView7" />
            <TextView
                android:minWidth="30px"
                android:minHeight="30px"
                xmlns="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                android:id="@+id/textView8" />
            <TextView
                android:minWidth="30px"
                android:minHeight="30px"
                xmlns="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                android:id="@+id/textView9" />
```

always the same at the end of every tablerow element. Once I delete them they do not reoccur  unless I reopen that file.

Comment: Can you explain more your problem ?

Comment: No. Nothing more to tell.